# Access iptables logs on Android

Tags: iptables

I'm attempting to diagnose a packet forwarding issue on my Android 9 phone.  I've added a `-j LOG` rule to my `FORWARD` chain.  How can I access the logged messages?

According to [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/enable-logging-in-iptables-on-linux/), I first need to alter the syslog configuration file which is either at `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.  However, neither of those files exist on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a different userland and indeed doesn't use these log files (even modern Linux desktop distros don't use these files usually). So, that guide is wrong today (even if it *claims* it was written not a month ago!)¹ for desktop Linux and wouldn't have ever applied to Android to begin with.

Now, `iptables` is *not* the usual way the Android userland interacts with netfilter / *btables in the kernel. So, it's unknown how that logging is *exactly* implemented – chances are that whoever built the kernel modules for the logging chain in the netfilter kernel side modified them.

**If**, however, the logging code itself is unmodified, then the packets will be logged to the *kernel log* (the thing you can read using `dmesg` on a desktop Linux). Now, it's unusual for an Android Linux to have the `dmesg` utility. Not that much of a problem – you can just read `/proc/kmsg` yourself.

---

¹ Hint: when you find a guide on a basic technology and it is from some random "tech advice" website, and especially if it claims a recent modification date, chances are it's machine-generated or cheaply-without-understanding-anything-copied-together content :( That's the sad state of the internet: Content generation from unquoted sources for the sole purpose of traffic maximization, hoping to scrape the bottom of the advertisement revenue barrel :( These clutter the top search engine results very reliably. Let me tell you (*shakes walking stick at cloud*) back in my day, searching the internet was actually better.

Comment: How *does* Android typically interact with netfilter?

Comment: through the netlink kernel interface, just like the `iptables` program does internally.

Comment: Oh, you mean like creating `AF_NETLINK` sockets?

Comment: https://netfilter.org/projects/libnftnl/index.html

Comment: "back in my day, searching the internet was actually better."  In my day, an "internet search" meant using AOL keywords.

Comment: @AugustVrubel :D not saying those were *not* the days, but honestly, Google's utility in finding technically accurate content has sharply dropped recently, especially since they default to "yeah I can just choose to ignore parts of your query, the search algorithm knows better than you" instead of "if a result doesn't contain all words from the query, it's not a result".